# Can the comma before "or" be removed when it provides extra information that could be similar to what has already been said?

Tags: grammar, commas, parenthetical-commas

For instance, would removing the comma be incorrect in "the painting was painted in 1862, or the 19th century"?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, yes it would be incorrect -- the phrase following **or** is an appositive phrase, and so it is nonessential.

Source: https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/commas/commas-with-appositives/

Comment: Thank you so much @FeliniusRex :)